# Relación entre un evento onclick html y jquery no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, datatables

estaba haciendo un proyecto de crear una página web y tenía una parte dónde se debía buscar un registro en la base de datos y listarlo.
Trataba de lograr que se pudiera editar el registro y para eso hice un evento onclick en un botón, que llamara una función de js y con jquery llenar un formulario para hacer la edición, pero cuando veo el formulario no aparecen los datos.
Usé "la misma técnica" para otros elementos y si funcionaba.

Este es un fragmento del código:

```
<tbody>
   <?php foreach ($tablaBusqueda as $key => $value) : ?>
      <tr style="background-color:#555555;">
         <td><?php echo $value['titulo']; ?></td>
         <td><button onclick="desc('<?php echo $value['descripcion']; ?>');" type="button"
            class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDes">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></td>
         <td><button onclick="imag('<?php echo $value['imagen']; ?>');" type="button" 
            class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalImg">
         <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </button></td>
         <td><?php echo $value['autor']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $value['fecha']; ?></td>
         <td>
             <button onclick="ed('<?php echo $value['idNoticia']; ?>',
                 '<?php echo addslashes($value['titulo']); ?>',
                 '<?php echo addslashes($value['descripcion']); ?>',
                 '<?php echo addslashes($value['imagen']); ?>',
                 '<?php echo addslashes($value['autor']); ?>');" 
                 type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalE">
                 <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
         </td>
     </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Luego el js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function desc(descripcion) {
        $('<p class="text-justify text-center">' + descripcion + '</p>').appendTo('#resultadoDesc');
    }

    function imag(imagen) {
        $('<img src="' + imagen + '" style="width:100%;"/>').appendTo('#resultadoImg');
    }

    function ed(idEd, title, descr, img,autor) {
        $('txtIdE').val(idE);
        $('txtTituloE').val(title);
        $('txtImagenE').val(img);
        $('txtAutorE').val(autor);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Entiendo que #resultadoDesc o #resultadoImg lo 'pinta' en el body del modal ?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona exactamente? ¿Qué has depurado y con qué resultados? ¿Da error y qué error es?

Comment: @A.Cedano, se supone que los valores de la tabla con el for deberían reflejarse en el formulario con los nombres que se usan en el js.
Sin embargo no se ven, intenté hacerlo por medio de id y tampoco se reflehan, sin embargo si sólo tomo un valor y lo devulevo funciona a la perfección, anteriormente no tenía la función addslashes, pero no funcionaba, creí que era porque la variable título contenía un caracter especial ( ' ).
Revisé el controlador y el modelo pero no arrojan errores cuando uso un try.
Además, las otras 2 funciones van a la perfección, tomando información de la misma variable

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño Sí, las funciones dec e imag no asingnan valores, directamente los insertan en un div con las id correspondientes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de revisar los posibles errores, me senté con un amigo que me animó a revisar desde lo más básico de nuevo.
El error simplemente era de escritura, cuando llamaba la variable idEd lo hacía sin la d: idE.

Código corregido:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function desc(descripcion) {
    $('<p class="text-justify text-center">' + descripcion + '</p>').appendTo('#resultadoDesc');
}

function imag(imagen) {
    $('<img src="' + imagen + '" style="width:100%;"/>').appendTo('#resultadoImg');
}

function ed(idEd, title, descr, img,autor) {
    $('txtIdE').val(idE);
    $('txtTituloE').val(title);
    $('txtImagenE').val(img);
    $('txtAutorE').val(autor);
}
```

Comment: Depurar, depurar, depurar y depurar es fundamental. Si la función `ed` te estaba fallando, con haber puesto un `console.log` que mostrase los parámetros `idEd, title, descr, img, autor` ya habrías estado encaminado a encontrar el error. Pues al ver que llegaban, el siguiente paso era revisar las referencias a los elementos y ahí habrías visto el error relativo a `$('txtIdE')`... Moraleja: depurar, depurar, depurar, depurar... Por eso mi pregunta: ***¿Qué has depurado y con qué resultados?***. Eso es lo primero que tienes que hacer cuando hay un problema, sin divagar en explicaciones lógicas.